# IIS7 php fastcgi - cannot change upload dir

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

My problem is, that the upload directory suddenly changed by a php application. I set it in php.ini to ../upload, and it worked for about 1 year. Now I don't know why, but php uploads to C:\Windows\Temp despite the php.ini-s upload settings.

There is another strange thing with that application. The web.config file doesn't work 
without the code:

```
        <handlers>
            <add name="iphonephpcgi" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\creation\software developer\projects\iphonetok\php-5.2.17\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
```

The other applications work well, and they uploads to the right directory. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Moved the project to a working directory. I don't know what was the problem.